# My supposedly thread-safe rotating file logger rotates only in debug mode, and doesn't crash only in release mode

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote what I wanted to be a thread-safe rotating file logger using Qt's loging framework.
Once the current log file (app.log) gets over a certain size, it should be renamed to app_prev.log (overwriting the old app_prev.log, if one exists), and a new, empty app.log should be created and written to.
I set the max log size to 10 bytes so that it'd rotate the logs right away to test it.
When I run it in release mode, app.log gets rewritten (as expected), but app_prev.log remains untouched (i.e. I lose the contents that were in app.log before the rotation instead of them being in app_prev).
When I run it in debug mode, it works as expected - but right after the log writing, I get a sigpipe (broken pipe) signal, which terminates my program... I don't see what I'm doing wrong here...

Here's a minimal version of my code:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <iostream>
#include <QMutexLocker>
#include <QMutex>

static constexpr int MAX_LOG_SIZE = 10; //1024*1024*10;  //10MB max log size.
static constexpr auto LOG_NAME = "app.log";
static constexpr auto PREV_LOG_NAME = "app_prev.log";

class LogFile {
public:

    static void write(QString msg) {
        QMutexLocker<QMutex> l(&_m);
        if (!_f.isOpen())
        {
            if (!_f.open(QFile::Append))
            {
                std::cerr << msg.toStdString() << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        _f.write(msg.toUtf8());
        _f.flush();
    }

    static int size() {
        QMutexLocker<QMutex> l(&_m);
        return _f.size();
    }

    static void rollover() {
        QMutexLocker<QMutex> l(&_m);
        _f.close();
        if (QFile::exists(PREV_LOG_NAME))
        {
            if (!QFile::remove(PREV_LOG_NAME))
                qFatal("Faile deleting prev log file.");
        }
        while (QFile::exists(PREV_LOG_NAME)) {
            sleep(1);
        }
        if (!_f.rename(PREV_LOG_NAME))
            qFatal("Failed renaming current log to prev log");
        _f.setFileName(LOG_NAME);
        if (!_f.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
            qFatal("Failed opening log for writing");
    }

private:
    static QFile _f;
    static QMutex _m;
};

QFile LogFile::_f = QFile(LOG_NAME);
QMutex LogFile::_m;

void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{

    auto line = (qFormatLogMessage(type, context, msg) + "\n");
    if (line.size() + LogFile::size() >= MAX_LOG_SIZE)
        LogFile::rollover();
    LogFile::write(line);
}

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qSetMessagePattern("[%{time yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.zzz t} %{if-debug}D%{endif}%{if-info}I%{endif}%{if-warning}W%{endif}%{if-critical}C%{endif}%{if-fatal}F%{endif}] %{file}:%{line} - %{message}");
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qInfo("Testing...");
}
```

Comment: Pop quiz: when `if (line.size() + LogFile::size() >= MAX_LOG_SIZE)` is true, what do you think will happen when you have multiple execution threads evaluating this line at the same time, and neither one of them has called `rollover()` yet? Fail. Multithreading is hard. P.S. What led you to conclude that SIGPIPE must be caused by something in the shown code, instead of all the other code in this application which is not shown?

Comment: I would modify the logic in `write` so it does the same thing when the file is open or closed. I would move the logic for rollover into `write` as well. No reason for an external function to make that decision and the check for if it is necessary and the logix to do it would all be inside the mutex lock so you wouldn't have a bunch of potential rollover calls stacking up waiting on the mutex and potentially rolling the file multiple times.

Comment: `_f.rename(PREV_LOG_NAME)` fails when the log file does not exist, which it doesn't if it's trying to roll over immediately before ever writing to it

Comment: @OP -- In the first comment: *what do you think will happen when you have multiple execution threads evaluating this line at the same time, and neither one of them has called rollover() yet?* -- And in your question: *I don't see what I'm doing wrong here...* -- To that point, do not try to make the "fix" by introducing a "normal" `bool` variable to toggle if rollover is being called.  If you do that, then you are not aware that individual lines of code can be entered by multiple threads, not just individual functions.  I say that since you do use mutexes, but only on a function level.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik good catch - I've removed size(), and changed it so write would be the only public function, and it would be the one calling rollover. Now there should not be any race condition.

Comment: You don't usually change the original question to show the working version. Now, there is no way to understand what was wrong and how you solved it. You could post an answer to your own question and show what you have changed to solve it.

Comment: @seleciii44 will do.

Comment: @feature_engineer you can also accept your own answer :) So that it's marked as solved.

Comment: @seleciii44 I can do that only 24 hours after posting the answer - 4 hours to go :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the comments above, the problem was with the logic of whether to call rollover being in a non-thread safe function.

Here's a working version of the code:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <iostream>
#include <QMutexLocker>
#include <QMutex>

static constexpr int MAX_LOG_SIZE = 10; //1024*1024*10;  //10MB max log size.
static constexpr auto LOG_NAME = "app.log";
static constexpr auto PREV_LOG_NAME = "app_prev.log";

class LogFile {
public:
    static void write(QString msg) {
        QMutexLocker<QMutex> l(&_m);
        if (!_f.isOpen())
        {
            if (!_f.open(QFile::Append))
            {
                std::cerr << msg.toStdString() << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (_f.exists() && (line.size() + LogFile::size()) >= MAX_LOG_SIZE)
            LogFile::rollover();
        _f.write(msg.toUtf8());
        _f.flush();
    }

private:
    static void rollover() {
        _f.close();
        if (QFile::exists(PREV_LOG_NAME))
        {
            if (!QFile::remove(PREV_LOG_NAME))
                qFatal("Faile deleting prev log file.");
        }
        while (QFile::exists(PREV_LOG_NAME)) {
            sleep(1);
        }
        if (!_f.rename(PREV_LOG_NAME))
            qFatal("Failed renaming current log to prev log");
        _f.setFileName(LOG_NAME);
        if (!_f.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
            qFatal("Failed opening log for writing");
    }

private:
    static QFile _f;
    static QMutex _m;
};

QFile LogFile::_f = QFile(LOG_NAME);
QMutex LogFile::_m;

void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{

    auto line = (qFormatLogMessage(type, context, msg) + "\n");
    LogFile::write(line);
}
```

There's now just a single point of entry guarded by a mutex, so the write operation is atomic, thus making race conditions impossible.

I've also made sure the original log exists before rename, So now at least one line would be written to the log before rollover.